# how to execute javascript in python with linke source

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

There I'm trying to execute java script in python `file.py`.

This is the code that I want to execute and I want to print the result.

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.9.0/js/client.min.js"></script>
<script>
// We generated a client token for you so you can test out this code
// immediately. In a production-ready integration, you will need to
// generate a client token on your server (see section below).
var clientToken = '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'



 braintree.client.create({
      authorization: clientToken
    });


</script>
```

I wanna to get the respond.

This is the respond when I run it

```
authorizationFingerprint: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIwMTgwNDI2MTYtcHJvZHVjdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6IkF1dGh5In0.eyJleHAiOjE1ODQ0NDUyNTMsImp0aSI6IjZkM2VhOTAzLTdjZjAtNDAwMy1hMGE0LTU0YzYxOGQ5Zjc5YyIsInN1YiI6Ijlnajdjc3BkeWg2NWN0d3EiLCJpc3MiOiJBdXRoeSIsIm1lcmNoYW50Ijp7InB1YmxpY19pZCI6Ijlnajdjc3BkeWg2NWN0d3EiLCJ2ZXJpZnlfY2FyZF9ieV9kZWZhdWx0IjpmYWxzZX0sInJpZ2h0cyI6WyJtYW5hZ2VfdmF1bHQiXSwib3B0aW9ucyI6e319.1n4GTB38ganetI6zzOUn9bTkljNjqHD8QImM9idXUWeMqoW5a9Z_bYKq_T03VZIWo6sPV3Fw8ATGHI34eHOPJQ
_meta[merchantAppId]: localhost
_meta[platform]: web
_meta[sdkVersion]: 3.9.0
_meta[source]: client
_meta[integration]: custom
_meta[integrationType]: custom
_meta[sessionId]: 7bf3978a-7c1d-4de1-a22a-5f471b471511
braintreeLibraryVersion: braintree/web/3.9.0
configVersion: 3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you searched for?

Comment: i wanna to generate  the authorization fingerprint and the sessionid in server side not in the customer side i will take from the customer the the card data and process it in server side before submit it to the third part